# C# - alternatives to using enums as unique identifiers

Tags: c#, enums, anti-patterns

I believe this is a common situation but couldn't find a satisfactory answer with Googling.

**Question:** Is there a pattern that addresses looking up enum values from the database?

**Situation:** I have been tasked with refactoring a Winforms app that is getting really heavy on memory usage. The main culprit is a "Constants" project - basically a bunch of Enum classes. Their purpose is to duplicate database lookup table values (see example below).

```
    public enum Status
    {
        None = -1,
        Active = 0,
        Completed = 1,
        Review = 2,
        Proceed = 3
    }
```

All of these enums have to be loaded in memory every single time the app loads. Is there a pattern that allows you to fix this problem, but also doesn't kill the database with queries?

Comment: Interesting question, +1. I'd never encountered a situation where enums were a culprit of a lot of memory use. Could you possibly share how you arrived at this conclusion?

Comment: How many enums do you have that it takes up that much memory?

Comment: also, speaking of duplication: you can remove those completely redundant comments.

Comment: I've used `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` instead of enums when the source exists in a repository.  However, to change to this would require a lot of refactoring due to the usage/syntax of enums.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx

Comment: This might help http://kijanawoodard.com/why-enums-suck

Comment: *The main culprit is a "Constants" project* How did you get to this conclusion?

Comment: @twn, Anthony, Alireza - I ran a JetBrains dotTrace trace on the app - while other objects get created and destroyed, there's one big blob of memory that remains in use - the Constants class. It is the largest component of memory that the app is using.

Comment: I disagree. How come you can come into a blind conclusion that `enum` is culprit? Do you know enum occupies only it's underlying type's memory? your `Status` enum will only use `4Byte` in memory. `Enum` maintains a table on calls to `GetNames` or `GetValues` for better performance. That shouldn't be much expensive! I suspect you'll be leaking memory somewhere else badly, try to find it. Answering this question is pointless unless you prove you're right.

Comment: Also, the situation encourages some development practices that I'd like the team to move away from; e.g. when adding a new entry to the db lookup tables, they guess the next available ID and hardcode it into the INSERT script, instead of using Sequence values.

Comment: Better check that Constants project (class?) to see if there's something else in there besides enums

Comment: Can you share how the values are taken from the database? Is it possible that the data objects used to populate the enums are not being disposed of properly? For the purpose of creating static enum objects for the life of the application, the current strategy looks pretty lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's quite hard to believe that an assembly of `enum`s could indeed be the main source of high memory usage (I don't even want to imagine the SIZE of that assembly), some possible solutions flow into mind:

1. Exploring your memory-greedy `enum` assembly for things other than `enum`s. Yes, it is a trivial advice, but it could prove the most reasonable after all.
2. Merging your `enum` assembly with main project. While `enum`s by themselves are hardly memory consuming, associated oversized assembly could well be all by itself (because of heavy usage of attributes, for instance).
3. Implementing necessary values with a bunch of not-necessarily `static` classes, filled with a bunch of `public static readonly int` fields (not `const`s). Hardly will reduce memory usage if all of them are called at least once, but could lead to some reduction depending on user's actions. However, those pesky `int`s are harder to account for then `enum`s.
4. Implementing necessary values with cached singleton-ish pattern (perhaps there is a name for such a pattern, but I am not familiar with it). While obviously harder on memory on a per-instance basis, it allows (while depending on GC) to be put into life and snuffed out of it based on usage. Basically, it should be something like

   ```
   internal abstract class ErzatsEnumBase {
       protected static readonly ObjectCache Cache = MemoryCache.Default;
       protected ErzatsEnumBase ( string CacheKey, CacheItemPolicy CachePolicy ) {
           Cache.Add ( CacheKey, this, CachePolicy, null );
       }
   }
   public sealed class ErzatsEnum: ErzatsEnumBase {
       private static CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy () {
           AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration,
           SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan ( 0, 15, 0 )
       };
       private ErzatsEnum ( string CacheKey )
           : base ( CacheKey, policy ) {
       }
       public ErzatsEnum Instance1 {
           get {
               ErzatsEnum result = ErzatsEnumBase.Cache.Get ( "Instance1" );
               if ( result == null )
                  result = new ErzatsEnum ( "Instance1" );
               return result;
           }
       }
       public ErzatsEnum Instance2 {
           get {
               ErzatsEnum result = ErzatsEnumBase.Cache.Get ( "Instance2" );
               if ( result == null )
                  result = new ErzatsEnum ( "Instance2" );
               return result;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope some of it proved useful :)